# NetSuite - Schedule Script Logic

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I want to create a monthly late fee invoice based on due date data from other invoices. For instance - late fee = £10 will be stored in a field based on due date calculation. So:

Company 1 - 5 invoices, 3 were paid late. Total fee invoice - £30
Company 2 - 3 invoices, 2 were paid late. Total fee invoice - £20
Company 3 - 7 invoices, 5 were paid late. Total fee invoice - £50

If I create a scheduled script that loops though all the invoices created in a month how would we say invoice company 1 £30, company 2 £20 and company 3 £50?

I need a way of grouping invoices that belong to a particular customer but as I am not passing any customer ID for example, how could I total up invoices for a particular customer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a Saved Search in the UI to group Invoices by Customer and sum the Totals or whatever field(s) you wish summarized. You can then invoke your Saved Search directly in your Scheduled Script, or export your Saved Search to raw SuiteScript using [this handy Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netsuite-search-export/gglbgdfbkaelbjpjkiepdmfaihdokglp).

You shouldn't need to pass in any specific Customer ID; you'll just be doing a search of all relevant invoices and iterating over the Customer groups that result.

If you're not sure exactly how to group or sum in the UI, just leave a comment, and I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I didn't consider using a saved search so that might be a possible solution. I'm not sure I can group invoices by customer since I need to apply a late fee on individual invoice based on - Days Overdue * Late Fee Charge.  
If I could somehow sum up the late fee charges from each invoice and show customer : total late fee charges that would make things much easier.

Comment: Actually I managed to group the late fee charges by doing the search from a customer. I just need to create a field that will show an int value if days_overdue date is greater than date_created date. Do you know we should do this? I tried adding a formula on the field > validation & defaulting > default value - {dcreated}-{duedate} but no value shows up...

Comment: Is `Store Value` checked on the field? If it is, formulas/sourcing will only happen when a new record is created. If you want the field to always be dynamically calculated, you have to uncheck `Store Value`, but I'm not sure how that would impact your searching.

Comment: Yeah I have the store value set - removing it seems to work for me. Thanks.